# How to add a udf to sqlContext in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am aware that I can register a Python function as UDFand use it in SQL query:

```
def example(s):
    return len(s)
sqlContext.udf.register("example_udf", example)
spark.sql("SELECT example_udf(col) FROM data")
```

Or I can wrap the Python function with `udf`, so it can be applied on dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
example_udf = udf(example)
data.select(example_udf('col'))
```

In my case, since I need to pass some other parameters to the UDF, I build a nested function for the UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
def my_udf(other_par)
    def example(s):
        return len(s) == other_par
    return udf(example, BooleanType())

dataframe.select(...).where(my_udf(5)(col('col')))
```

Now I have a UDF already, and I can applied it on dataframe. But I would also like to use it in spark.sql, like the SQL query in the first block, instead of dataframe's select or where method. So I am wondering how I can do that. It looks like `sqlContext.udf.register` can only accept Python function instead of a UDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use latest and greatest (2.3) just don't use `udf` directly:

```
def my_udf(other_par, spark):
    def _(s):
        return len(s) == other_par
    return spark.udf.register("my_udf_{}".format(other_par), _, BooleanType())

my_udf_42 = my_udf(42, spark)

spark.sql("SELECT my_udf_42(array(1, 2))").show()
# +----------------------+
# |my_udf_42(array(1, 2))|
# +----------------------+
# |                 false|
# +----------------------+

spark.createDataFrame([([1] * 42, )], ("id", )).select(my_udf_42("id")).show()
# +-------------+
# |my_udf_42(id)|
# +-------------+
# |         true|
# +-------------+
```

Otherwise invoke registering side effect directly:

```
def my_udf(other_par, spark):
    def _(s):
        return len(s) == other_par
    name = "my_udf_{}".format(other_par)
    spark.udf.register(name, _, BooleanType())
    return udf(_, BooleanType())

my_udf_0 = my_udf(0, spark)

spark.sql("SELECT my_udf_0(array())").show()
# +-----------------+
# |my_udf_0(array())|
# +-----------------+
# |             true|
# +-----------------+
```

Of course simple operations like this shouldn't be done with `udf`, but I assume it is just a toy example. If not,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import size, length

size("some_col") == 42
length("some_col") == 42
```

are better alternatives.